# How do I change the width size of the blocks in Moodle? It is CSS? What is the file?

Tags: php, css, moodle

**o css no caminho /www/moodle/theme/mytheme/style : custom.css**

```
/* Custom CSS

-------------------------*/



body {

    background:  url([[pix:theme|bg]]) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

    padding-top: 60px;

    color: #58585A;

    font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

    font-size: 14px;

    line-height: 20px;

    margin: 0;

}



#page {

    padding-top: 47px;

}



a.logo {

    background: url([[setting:logo]]) no-repeat 0 0;

    display: block;

    float: left;

    height: 75px;

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

    width: 100%;

}



.dir-rtl a.logo {

    background: url([[setting:logo]]) no-repeat 100% 0;

    display: block;

    float: right;

}



.navbar-inner{

    background: #F5F5F5;

}



.navbar .navbar-inner a.brand span {

    display: none;

}





.navbar .navbar-inner a.brand {

    background-image: url([[pix:theme|logo]]);

    background-position: center center;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    min-height: 74px;

    padding: 5px 20px;

    width: 214px;

}



.navbar .nav {

    margin-top: 17px;

}



.navbar-text, .navbar .nav > li > a{color:#E8770D;}



.breadcrumb {



    border-radius: 4px;

    list-style: none outside none;

    margin: 0 0 20px;

    padding: 8px 15px;  

    background-color: #FFFFFF;

    border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;

}

.coursebox {

    border: 1px dotted #DDDDDD;

    border-radius: 4px;

    margin-bottom: 15px;

    padding: 5px;

    background:#f5f5f5;

}



/* Custom CSS Settings

-------------------------*/
```

[[setting:customcss]]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Could you make your post shorter and more readable?

Comment: I changed this code several times, but nothing changes, up erasing all the code does not change anything on the page. I believe that this is not the CSS file, but this is what is inside the theme installed.

Answer (score 1):

Moodle puts all the css into one file for speed. To turn this off, add this line to config.php - on a development site not a production site...

```
$CFG->themedesignermode = true;
```

Then in Chrome, refresh the page, right click on the block and inspect element. It should now show the original css file.

After you have finished, remove the themedesignermode line or set it to false because it will make the site verrrry slow... http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_theme#Theme_designer_mode

You might also need to purge the cache after making any changes - http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Purge_all_cache